# Static files aren't being served by foreman in my Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, foreman

I'm using Heroku to deploy a simple Sinatra app which I am using to host JavaScript games.

All the static assets are saved in the /public directory.

When I run the app locally, i.e. '$ruby bin/app.rb', I am able to access static assets from the folder. However when I instead start a local server with foreman, I get a 404 error; 'Sinatra doesn't know this ditty'.

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec ruby bin/app.rb -p $PORT
```

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'json', '1.8.1'
```

bin/app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

set :views, "views"
set :public_folder, "public"

get '/' do
  redirect '/index.html'
end

get '/play/:game' do
etc.
```

Directory structure:

```
-bin
  app.rb
-public
  image.png
  some other static files
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
Procfile
```

When running the sinatra app, /image.png shows me the image without problem. When running on foreman, /image.png returns a 404 error.

Does anyone have any clue what might be going on here?

Comment: You’re specifying a rather old version of Sinatra in your `Gemfile`. The name of the `public_folder` setting was just `public` in this version. I don’t think it should really matter in this case as you’re using the default name of the directory in question, but it would be worth updating to a more recent version if you can. (You might be running a different version if you just do `$ ruby bin/app.rb` from when you run `foreman`.)

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that [Ruby v2.1.2 is supported on Heroku now too](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions), no need to use 1.9.3